# Hebrew file names as ???.txt

Tags: filenames, unicode

on Linux I see Hebrew file names as ???.txt using putty . on WinScp it looks fine. is it a putty issue or Linux (shell) issue ?
when I run locale I'm getting in the LANG : LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Check if character set on both sides of the ssh connection. They must be identical.

1) You already checked the character set on remote host. According to you `LANG` variable, it is `UTF-8`.

2) Check now the character set in putty configuration. Under "Window|Translation", the `remote character set` must match the one declared by `LANG` variable.

[image: putty configuration screenshot]

Comment: yes both setting are good , so it is not it